# How to create ButtonGroup of JToggleButton's that allows to deselect the actual option?

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

That's it. I need to create a ButtonGroup that allows to select a option or, if the user click on the selected option, deselect the item (nothing will be selected) and, of course, capture the event to do something.

Comment: That might not be intuitive for the user. Have you thought about making one option to represent the state/choice that would correspond to the deselection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just in case Jeff's link is broken in the future, here's what's described:
you need to subclass ButtonGroup to allow a no-selection, and add your buttons to this buttongroup.

```
public class NoneSelectedButtonGroup extends ButtonGroup {

  @Override
  public void setSelected(ButtonModel model, boolean selected) {
    if (selected) {
      super.setSelected(model, selected);
    } else {
      clearSelection();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or an anonymous inner class will suffice, e.g., `ButtonGroup myGroup = new ButtonGroup(){ /*code from above*/ };`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227537/2506021) refines this to avoid clearing the selection calling `button.setSelected(false)` on a button/checkbox that is not selected.

Answer (score 5):

This shows exactly how to do that https://dzone.com/articles/unselect-all-toggle-buttons

Answer (score 1):

I noticed weird behavior when doing `button.setSelected(false)` on a button/checkbox that is not selected. It deselected everything as if I deselected something.

I fixed it this way:

```java
public class NoneSelectedButtonGroup extends ButtonGroup {

  @Override
  public void setSelected(ButtonModel model, boolean selected) {
    if (selected) {
      super.setSelected(model, selected);
    } else if (getSelection() != model) {
      clearSelection();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the event to do something. Also do the below.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ((JToggleButton)e.getSource()).setSelected(false);
}
```

**EDIT:**
But there is no ButtonGroup involved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for pre java 1.6

```
public class NoneSelectedButtonGroup extends ButtonGroup {
    private AbstractButton hack;

    public NoneSelectedButtonGroup() {
        super();
        hack = new JButton();
        add(hack);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(ButtonModel model, boolean selected) {
        super.setSelected(selected ? model : hack.getModel(), true);
    }
}
```